# Can't duplicate a proxy armature with mesh

Tags: animation, armature, linked-data, instances

### **My problem:**

I have a rigged character as an asset of a master-scene in its own .blend-file. The asset.blend contains the character and its animations. To make use of my character and its animations in the master-scene I link the Character and make its armature a proxy one.

This allows me to access different actions from the action editor and it will always be updated if I ever want to add some more animations to the character or some changes to the mesh.

Now, since I want multiple instances of my linked character, I tried to copy and paste my armature and the mesh.

---

**I expected** to have another character (a sheep to be exact) with an individual armature that can have different actions selected.

---

**What happens is** that both meshes are only controlled by the second instance of the armature

[image]

---

What am I doing wrong? Is there a work-arround or is it possible at all?

---

I created a demo project for you, so you can try it yourself.

[Download .blend-files (ZIP)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B89oIuOBdiu0TzJKbDgtVUNhX0U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: duplicating armatures has to be done in object mode, not in pose mode. anyway, you can change wich armature your mesh uses in the armature modifier properties. Can't say more without the blend file.

Comment: @Bithur I was in Object mode when I copied them. The problem is, when I duplicate or reimport the proxy armature. The Armature has the exact same name in both instances, so therefore I have no choice between to different armatures in the dropdown. It's only listed once.

Comment: are you using duplicates (Shift+D) or linked duplicates (Alt+D) ?

Comment: @Bithur I tried both, ended up with the exact same result

Comment: there's something wrong, upload the blend file

Comment: @Bithur I updated my question and attached demo-files. One master.blend, where I link to the asset.blend that contains the "character with armature and animations".

Comment: too many links for me. object, armature, actions...i'm not able to deal with that...sorry

Comment: @Bithur no problem

Comment: what i think is : make everything local (objects, vertex data, armature and armature data) and use action editor and NLA to make animation things local and single user, where i can't help

Answer (score 2):

I Believe this is a limitation from the current linking implementation. The workaround I currently use is to create a copy of the file (or a file link if the os supports that) with a different name and link the second character from that.

Comment: I heard about that workaround, but I hoped for a better way to do it, since I always want the same action library in all the copied files than. But well, looks like I have to deal with it.